# Insert new XML node using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

XML:
    
     
      1
      aaa
      
     
     
      2
      bbb

Code

```
var doc = XDocument.Load (Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Questions.config");
var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("Question")
               select new
               {
                   Id = element.Element("Id").Value,
                   Text = element.Element("Text").Value,
                   Reserver = element.Element("Reserver") != null
               };

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var question in elements)
{
    builder.AppendLine(question.Id + "-" + question.Text);
}
myTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

how insert new Node 'Question' to XML File

Comment: accept the answer if it helped you. you'll get reputation too

Comment: What do you want to update the value *to*, in the XML? You've given sample input - what do you want the output to be?

Comment: updata 'aaa' to 'kkk' by linq

Comment: @beginner: And where does the value "kkk" come from?

Comment: You mean I do not understand. 'kkk' is from MyTextBox

Comment: @beginner: *From* your text box? Currently you're only updating the value *of* your text box, not the XML at all. Could I suggest you read my guide to asking SO questions effectively? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what your question means, but the basic process of updating the XML file would be along the lines of:

- Load the XML document into memory, as you're already doing
- Identify the element you want to change, which will depend on what the criteria are
- Update it (e.g. setting the Value property to "kkk" as per your comments)
- Save the XML document using `doc.Save("file.xml")` or something similar

It's hard to be more precise than that without having more precise requirements. As an example though, if you wanted to prefix every `Text` node in the document with "Question x: " where x is the ID of the question, you might write something like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var elements = doc.Descendants("Question");

foreach (var question in elements)
{
    int id = (int) question.Element("ID");
    XElement textElement = question.Element("Text");
    textElement.Value = "Question: " + id + " = " + textElement.Value;
}

doc.Save("changed.xml");
```

Or to change every "aaa" Text element to "kkk":

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var elements = doc.Descendants("Text")
                  .Where(x => x.Value == "aaa");

foreach (var textElement in elements)
{
    textElement.Value = "kkk";
}

doc.Save("changed.xml");
```

Comment: what is doc.Save("changed.xml"); <"changed.xml">

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
var doc = XDocument.Load (Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Questions.config");
var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("Question")
               select new
               {
                   Id = element.Element("Id").Value,
                   Text = element.Element("Text").Value,
                   Reserver = element.Element("Reserver") != null
               };

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var question in elements)
{
    builder.AppendLine(question.Id + "-" + question.Text);
}
myTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

**EDIT:** If you want to update *every* question then you have to slightly modify the code above.

```
var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("Question")
               select new
               {
                   Id = element.Element("Id"),
                   Text = element.Element("Text"),
                   Reserver = element.Element("Reserver")
               };
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var question in elements)
{
    // Read
    builder.AppendLine(question.Id.Value + "-" + question.Text.Value);

    // Write
    question.Reserver.Value = "True";
}
myTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

In this way you don't select the value anymore but the XElement instead, so you're able to modify the XML. Remember also to save the file using `XDocument.Save()`.

Comment: tanks . very very very muck . how can updata xml by linq

Comment: It's unclear to me why this answer has been accepted, given that it doesn't modify the XML at all...

Comment: Hi Jon, the question was different previously. Take a look at the edits ;) Anyway I have updated it with the new requests.

Comment: @AS-CII: Yes, I hadn't seen the edits - but your answer still doesn't appear to be modifying the XML.

Comment: question.Reserver.Value = "True"; this not work that update Reserver=true

Comment: This is an example of how to modify a value in Linq-to-XML. If you want to edit `Text` element as you recently updated in your question you have just to replace `question.Reserver.Value = "True";` with `question.Text.Value = "kkk";`

Comment: @AS-CII: Ah, I hadn't noticed that you'd changed the anonymous type to select the elements instead of the values. Yes, that changes the XML (although not the file :)

Comment: I specified to save at the end :) Anyway it seems that your answer was better ;)