# Update and Add new Tag inside XML

Tags: c#, xelement

Below is example of my XML:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer Id="1" Name="abc"/>
  <Customer Id="2" Name="efg"/>
</Customers>
```

How to update inside this XML using XElement?

```
<Customer Id="1" Name="aaabbbccc"/>
```

And How to add new row inside this xml??

```
<Customers>
  <Customer Id="1" Name="abc"/>
  <Customer Id="2" Name="efg"/>
  <Customer Id="3" Name="test"/>
</Customers>
```

And, how to get specfied name?
For e.g, if 1 then abc, if 2 then efg

Sorry but I have no idea, new to XML and XElement.

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend using LINQ to XML (in namespaces `System.Linq` and `System.Xml.Linq`);

```
// Load Xml
string xml = "";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Get and modify element
if (doc.Root != null)
{
    var elementToModify = doc.Root.Elements("Customer").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == "2");
    if (elementToModify != null) elementToModify.SetAttributeValue("Name", "aaabbbccc");
}

// Add new Element
XElement customer = doc.Descendants("Customers").FirstOrDefault();
if (customer != null) customer.Add(new XElement("Customer", new XAttribute("Id", 3), new XAttribute("Name", "test")));

// OR (maddy's answer)
doc.Element("Customers").Add(new XElement("Customer", new XAttribute("Id", 3), new XAttribute("Name", "test")));

// OR (Richard's answer)
doc.Root.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Customer", new XAttribute("Id", 3), new XAttribute("Name", "test")));
```

EDIT:

```
// Get the Name attribute for a specified Id.
XElement element = doc.Root.Elements("Customer").Single(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value == "1");
string name = element.Attribute("Name").Value; // will be "abc"
```

Comment: How about to get the name for specified id? E.g: if 1 then is abc

Comment: This code will get your all elements with the id attribute set to "YOUR_ID".
doc.Root.GetDescendants().Where(p => p.Attributes["id"].Where(p => p.Value == "YOUR_ID");

Comment: See my updated answer. ( @Gusdor that returns an IEnumerable<XElement>, OP wants the name attribute )

Comment: I guess the modify won't work this way, it should be updated, check my answer below

Comment: @AliIssa Why? It's the same as yours? You mean the check for null?

Comment: @SamLeach no I meant this: doc.Elements("Customers").Elements("Customer")

Comment: @SamLeach welcome :), it works in both ways mine and yours so upvote for you

Answer (score 2):

Check these links which can help a lot (using linq is one of the best ways):

1. [add data to existing xml file using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783525/add-data-to-existing-xml-file-using-linq)
2. [Adding element to XML using linq to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554602/adding-element-to-xml-using-linq-to-xml)
3. [Insert new XML node using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289806/insert-new-xml-node-using-linq)

As an example I just did:

```
    string customers = "<Customers><Customer Id=\"1\" Name=\"abc\"/><Customer Id=\"2\" Name=\"efg\"/></Customers>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(customers);
    XElement element = new XElement("Customer", new XAttribute("Id", "3"), new XAttribute("Name", "test"));
    doc.Element("Customers").Add(element);
    doc.Save(xmlfilepath);
```

To Modify:

```
    var myElement = doc.Elements("Customers").Elements("Customer").Where(el => el.Attribute("Id").Value == "2").SingleOrDefault();
    if (myElement != null)
        myElement.SetAttributeValue("Name", "aaabbbccc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using LINQ to XML which is perhaps the easiest of the .NET XML APIs to use:

For the first part: updating the value of an attribute, you need to get the [`XAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) instance for the `Name` attribute and change its value:

```
custElement.Attribute("Name").Value = "aaabbbccc";
```

assuming `CustElement` is the right `<Customer>` element.

For the second part: append another element, to insert an element *after* another use the [`AddAfterSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154665.aspx) method of [`XNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx) (parent of [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)), so given `rootElement` being an `XElement` for the `<Customers>` element:

```
rootElement.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Customer",
                                               new XAttribute("Id", 3),
                                               new XAttribute("Name", "test")));
```

(The first parameter of `XElement`'s constructor is its name, subsequent ones are content—either attributes (as in this case) or child nodes. There are multiple other ways to do this: eg. [`Add(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061.aspx) to append to an `XElement` wrapping the `<Customers>` element, but in practice one tends to have ones own preference and stick to it (a small consistency making code a little simpler).

For the third part: get customer by id we can just use a LINQ comprehension expression:

```
var matches = (from cust in customersElement.Elements("Customer")
              where (int)cust.Attribute("Id") == theTargetId
              select cust)
              .Single();
```

(This will throw if anything other than exactly one match is found, use `SingleOrDefault` to return `null` on not found.)

Comment: How about to get the name for specified id? E.g: if 1 then is abc

Comment: @kingjia Oops... too many questions in one question so missed that. Will expand.